# Text white line over background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a website, so I used a Bootstrap template [(this one)](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full/). It's an empty template with just a background image that covers the whole page (I took the navbar away).

I just tried entering random text in the html body section, and then this problem appears.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3VP8.png)

The code from the template is untouched (besides deleting the navbar). I just added a common html paragraph.

I want to get rid of that white line, so only the text appears above the background, not the background. I've tried setting the body style to background-color: transparent, tried tweaking position, z-index and whatnot and the white line does not disappear. Googling has not helped.

I would appreciate your help of how to get rid of this!

Comment: can you post the CSS associated with the element causing the white background?  have a link to the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background colour of the content you've added is being computed from the background colour of the body tag.

The problem with that template is that the background image is being placed on the html tag rather than the body. You can try placing the full class on the body.

```
<body class="full">
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the font properties. If the font properties are clear, then back up and examine the paragraph, li, ul, block or div.

Comment: Font is the default, I have not set any. Body div is like this: body {
  margin: 0;
}
There is no li, block or anything. 
<body>

    <!-- Put your page content here! -->
<p>Hola mundo</p>
[...]